# How do I interpret "K2 mod K1"?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, jordan-normal-form, quotient-spaces

I've been doing a bit of work these past couple of nights on computing cyclic subspace decompositions, finding cyclic bases, and then computing the Jordan canonical form of matrices.

My question is:  When I compute, say, generalized eigenvectors that are in the nullspace of $(A-\lambda I)^2$, call this nullspace $K_2$, and I pick a vector from $K_2$ that is *not* in $K_1$, which is the null space of $(A-\lambda I)$, why is it called, "the vector is in $K_2$ mod $K_1$".

I've learned the word "modulo" in an introductory proofs class as something like this: $x$ is congruent to $y$ mod $z$, if $(x-y)/z$ yields an integer.

But I don't see how this definition helps with my understanding of "$K_2 mod K_1$".

Also, I think that $K_2$ mod $K_1$ is a "quotient space", which vaguely means that $K_1$ collapses to the zero vector - so does this mean that $K_2$ mod $K_1$ is just a "smaller" vector space, the vector space $K_2$ + a zero vector, $K_1$?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question mentions you are vaguely aware we might be speaking of quotient spaces. Have you looked up the term? Anything in, say, the Wikipedia article that you're having trouble following? Anyway, the time it would take to discuss what quotient spaces are and how this comment might be interpreted in light of them makes their word choice unjustified in my opinion. They should just say "pick a vector $v\in K_2\setminus K_1$."

Comment: Ah, right @anon.  Yes, I think I will stick with your suggestion.  Yes, I have a bunch of notes on quotient spaces and have read through all of it pretty thoroughly.  But when the term comes up, either in class or in problems to solve, I again wonder to myself "what is all this modulo business"?  Another example:  in an elliptic functions lecture, what exactly is "C modulo the lattice" that my professor keeps saying?  Is this *also* a quotient space, *or* really just the complex plane, *minus* the chosen lattice points?  Using your suggestion again would be better...

Comment: It absolutely does not mean set-theoretic difference. With $\Bbb C/\Lambda$, it is both a quotient group and a quotient space (which ends up being a complex manifold / Riemann surface). You should really look into quotients if you are having trouble understanding what they are. They are important! Anyway, for what it's worth, saying that one is choosing something in $A$ mod $B$ in this context likely means one is choosing something in $A$, and *additionally* is parenthetically saying what will happen next will only depend on which coset of $B$ you chose it from.

Comment: Note further that (a) saying the vector is "in $K_2$ mod $K_1$" (somewhat abusively) and (b) the fact the vector is chosen to be in $K_2$ but not in $K_1$ are *unrelated* comments.

Comment: Hi @anon ok got it - thanks so much for the discussion.  I will read up on this stuff today and tomorrow :-). Have a great night.